# Facebook authentication in Samsung

Tags: android

I am using the Facebook sdk for posting to the timeline in my application. It's working fine on the Google Nexus, Motorola. When it comes to the samsung s3 I get the following error:

```
This app has no android key hashes configured, configure your app key hashes at http://developers.facebook.com/apps
```

I don't understand why I am getting this on the samsung s3.

Comment: hmm, where's the image

Comment: sorry,I didnt have enough reputations, error dialog with (This app has no android key hashes configured ,configur your app key hashes at http://developers.facebook.com/apps) ,     and button okay. I am getting this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to obtain hash key or if you have already obtain configure it first below are the link to obtain and configure hash keys.

Register the package and activity with Facebook using [this link](http://developers.facebook.com/apps)

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

check step no 6 to configure hash key

Comment: I went through mobile apps---> android--->then where should I go

Comment: no, I didnt understand eventhough I am using facebook sdk,application is redirected to default facebook app.how to restrict this.\

Comment: just read second link properly then you will be able to do everything ;)

Comment: Default android facebook app is getting called,is there any way to stop this.

Comment: There may be a same package name you are using,change package name of your application then register your application, it should work

Comment: my package name is like com.myprojectname.facebook,and I dont know package name of  facebook app downloaded from playstore,I dont think that these package names are same

Comment: ohhh i see, then try to search out in your code if you are calling default FB application from some where .

Comment: no,when I uninstall default facebook app I am getting  facebook dialog and everything is fine.